# Show that $\frac{a_1}{b_1}+\frac{a_2}{b_2}+...+\frac{a_n}{b_n} \geq n$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Let $a_1$, $a_2$,..., $a_n$ be the sequence of positive numbers, and
>   let $b_1$, $b_2$,..., $b_n$ be any permutation of the first sequence.
>   Show that $$\frac{a_1}{b_1}+\frac{a_2}{b_2}+...+\frac{a_n}{b_n} \geq
> n$$

This is a preparation Question PUTNAM contest. The theme of the section is "inequality". I can not make the problem from inequality. Is anyone is able give me a hint (using inequalities)?

Comment: We can also use the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hint: AM-GM. Note that the product of our fractions is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple, but just to clarify even more:

$\dfrac{\dfrac{a_1}{b_1} + \dfrac{a_2}{b_2} + ... + \dfrac{a_n}{b_n}}{n} \geq \sqrt[n]{\dfrac{a_1}{b_1}\dfrac{a_2}{b_2} ... \dfrac{a_n}{b_n}}$

But $\dfrac{a_1}{b_1}\dfrac{a_2}{b_2} ... \dfrac{a_n}{b_n} = 1$

Then,

$\dfrac{\dfrac{a_1}{b_1} + \dfrac{a_2}{b_2} + ... + \dfrac{a_n}{b_n}}{n}\geq 1$

Then it follows that,

$\dfrac{a_1}{b_1} + \dfrac{a_2}{b_2} + ... + \dfrac{a_n}{b_n}\geq n$

I hoped to have made it better understood, and just to let the Geometric-Arithmetic inequality for general use, this is, Geometric Mean is always smaller equal than arithmetic mean.